# How to enter docker container use shell script and do something?

Tags: linux, docker, shell, containers

I want to enter my container and do something, then leave this container.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i ubuntu-lgx bash << EOF

echo "test file" >> /inner.txt
ls -l /inner.txt
content=`cat /inner.txt`
echo ${conent}                                                             

# do something else

EOF
```

when I run this script, the bash tell me the file is not exist.but the `ls` can output the file's property.

```sh
cat: /inner.txt: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 58 Nov 14 11:51 /inner.txt
```

where am I wrong? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not protecting your "here" document from local shell expansion. When you write:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i ubuntu-lgx bash << EOF

content=`cat /inner.txt`

EOF
```

That `cat /inner.txt` is run on your *local* system, not the remote system. The contents of here document are parsed for variable expansion and other shell features.

To prevent that, write it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i ubuntu-lgx bash << 'EOF'

echo "test file" >> /inner.txt
ls -l /inner.txt
content=`cat /inner.txt`
echo ${content}                                                             

# do something else

EOF
```

The single quotes in `'EOF'` are a signal to the shell to interpret the here document verbatim.

Comment: @LiuGuangxuan It doesn't make a difference here, but I recommend to use the `$(command)` syntax over backquotes, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: @hek2mgl ok,got it.